# Added new action in get_bulk_actions() of WP_List_Table. How to make it as default option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have added a new action as below :

```
 function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = array(
        'bulkemail'    => 'Bulk Email',
    );
    return $actions;
}
```

I want this Bulk Email as default selected value. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add this function `bulk_actions`

```
        protected function get_bulk_actions()
        {
                 $actions = array(
                'bulkemail'    => 'Bulk Email',
            );
            return $actions;
        }

        protected function bulk_actions( $which = '' ) {


        if ( is_null( $this->_actions ) ) {
          $this->_actions = $this->get_bulk_actions();

          $this->_actions = apply_filters( "bulk_actions-{$this->screen->id}", $this->_actions );
          $two = '';
        } else {
          $two = '2';
        }

        if ( empty( $this->_actions ) )
          return;

        echo '<label for="bulk-action-selector-' . esc_attr( $which ) . '" class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Select bulk action' ) . '</label>';
        echo '<select name="action' . $two . '" id="bulk-action-selector-' . esc_attr( $which ) . "\">\n";
       // echo '<option value="-1">' . __( 'Bulk Actions' ) . "</option>\n";

        foreach ( $this->_actions as $name => $title ) {
          $class = 'edit' === $name ? ' class="hide-if-no-js"' : '';

          echo "\t" . '<option value="' . $name . '"' . $class . ' selected>' . $title . "</option>\n";
        }

        echo "</select>\n";

        submit_button( __( 'Apply' ), 'action', '', false, array( 'id' => "doaction$two" ) );
        echo "\n";
      }
```